# Recalculate Functionality

Tags: excel, office-js

Recalculate is working for single column batching. It is loading last selected batched values if applied for multiple column batching. Kindly help to fix so that for respective selected columns value should bind in respective columns.

For ex. if batching applied on columns B,C and D and trying to execute recalculate then column's D value is being applied in column B and C also. It should binded respective column values based on respective column selections.

We applied below logic to achieve Recalculate.

```
function Recalculatee(event:any)
{
Excel.run((context)=>
{
context.workbook.application.calculate('Full');
return context.sync();
});
event.completed();
}
```

Comment: Could you let us know how did you define columns B,C and D to recalc? As we understanding, you should use range.calculate instead of application.calculate. And what's the expected behavior and actual behavior (column B and C's value are overwritten by column D's value?)? It will be great if you can share a sample excel file to repro the issue.

Comment: Yes. If we apply recalculate for three columns B,C and D then last selected values (D) are overwritten B and C columns.                                                                   Actual Result : B,C and D columns are showing same values of any of last selected column.                                                                                    
Expected Result:  Irrespective of selected columns respective columns should binded with respective values.

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                            
Any update?                                                                                                                              If we apply multiple columns last binded column values showing in all columns.

Comment: Hi Muruga, we couldn't repro the issue you mentioned. Is that possible you can give us your repro script and workbook, and a repro video will be great. My mailbox is ruoyingl@microsoft.com. Please feel free to send mail to me. Thanks!

Comment: 1) In manifest mentioned below steps                                                     
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton13">              
                                 ///other codes removed due to space constraints
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>ReCalculatee</FunctionName>
                  </Action>                   
                </Control>  and called method ReCalculatee as mentioned in first step.

Comment: Am i making clear and still any clarification?

Comment: Tried with below code change as you suggested but still same behavior.                                         function Recalculatee(event:any)
{
Excel.run((context)=>
{
const range=context.workbook.worksheets..getActiveWorksheet();
range.getRange().calculate();
return context.sync();
});
event.completed();
}

Comment: Thanks for the information. We still miss one piece: what's the B, C, D's value?  what's the calculation's logic? A repro video or the sample workbook will be a great help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have fixed the issue which belongs to business logic of validation.